# Office 365 REST API showing Calendar's which are already deleted

Tags: rest, odata, ms-office, office365, office365-restapi

I managed to query all the calendars from a user:

https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/xxxx@xxxx.com/calendars?$top=50

> getting up to 50 calendars from the user

Unfortunately, the query also returns deleted calendars from the user as well. I did not find a OData field to indicate deleted calendars (https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#OdataQueryParams) or similar.

What I did was the following: 
I logged in as the user in Microsoft Outlook and deleted a calendar from the user in the client. After closing and reopening Outlook, the calendar was deleted as expected. But when I query for all calendars via the REST API I still get the calendar which I deleted but no way to distinguish what the user can actually see, as all fields returned do not include anything pointing to the fact that it is a deleted calendar.

What can I do to get the same view on the calendars as the user gets with the client, or how do I "really" manage to delete a calendar without the REST API returning it?

If I can chose, I would rather know how to distinguish them properly ;)

Comment: I see this but the deleted calendar eventually drops out of the results after a minute or so. Do you not see the same?

Comment: @JasonJohnston yes the entry eventually disappeared also for me, although it took a whole day at my end. I do not know if a re-authorization of the access token could help here, but I think it is still something microsoft should fix.

Comment: I wonder if you're having a delay in syncing changes from Outlook. If you can still reproduce this long delay, can you also still see the calendar in OWA?